# What does "yanis' mean

Tags: meaning, slang

It's again from one of my favourite YouTube show "Screen Rant". I am confused about the word "yanis". What it means, has it a synonum?
https://youtu.be/Zk_YKmtOYyI?t=318 5:18

Comment: He doesn't say "yanis", and I can't work out what you are hearing.  He says: "So then the game starts and the goon squad scores over a thousand points, because you get points for style and stuff, whatever./ How does the scoring system work?/ No idea"

Comment: @JamesK Actually the next sentence is where he said "yanis". I've just copied url with 10 sec before the needed word in order to form a notion. So 5:18-5:20

Comment: I think it was 'that is'.

Comment: @KateBunting I'm not sure that's true 'cause "It's gonna be hard for that is to feel any stakes" has no sense

Comment: Obviously I was listening to the wrong sentence. He said "It's gonna be hard for _the_ [something]-ies", presumably the name or nickname of a team, but I know nothing about American sport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word is "audience"

> So then the game starts and the goon squad scores over a thousand points, because you get points for style and stuff, whatever.
>
> How does the scoring system work?
>
> No idea. It's just gonna be all over the place
>
> Err, it's gonna be hard for the **audience** to feel any stakes if the scoring is arbitrary.
>
> Actually, yup.
>
> Okay.

I've tried listing to this and I can't hear "yanis".  There is a bit of a slur as the /iː/ of "the" blends to "audience" giving something like /ðiːjɑːdiəns/

Comment: Thanks again. This pronunciation is entirely killing me, hope one day I'll be able to understand native speakers

Comment: Just think how hard it is for learners of Russian!  All those sh, ch and Shch sounds, and "hard and soft consonants that sound indistinguishable to me.

Comment: We can continue this chain and try to realize how difficult to learn one of the Asian languages. Asian alphabet, dependency on intonation and totally unusual accents and sounds. Anyway I am glad to know someone is learning russian, one of the most beautiful languages in the world in my opinion. Good luck!

Comment: Now that I know it's 'the audience' I can hear it, but the vowel is so different from the one I would use that I thought he was saying something like 'the yahnies'. (I sometimes put the subtitles on when I'm watching American TV shows!)